# Syntax error in Dr Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

The window keeps saying there is a error on the last part where it says `(...(count-even-strings (rest alist)))`
saying that it found on extra part but I just don't know how to fix it.

```
;; consumes a list of strings, list, and produces the number of strings in list that have an even length

(define (count-even-strings alist)
  (cond
    [(empty? alist) 0]
    [else (+ (cond [(even? (string-length (first alist))) true]) 1)]
[else 0]) (count-even-strings (rest alist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an editor that aligns properly the code, like DrRacket, you could see that your function has the following structure:

```
(define (count-even-string1s alist)
  (cond
    [(empty? alist) 0]
    [else (+ (cond [(even? (string-length (first alist))) true])
             1)]
    [else 0])
  (count-even-strings1 (rest alist)))
```

and has two `else` inside the same `cond`, which is not correct sintactically, while the last part is outside of the `cond`.

A correct solution with the use of `if` is the following:

```
 (define (count-even-strings alist)
  (if (empty? alist)
      0
      (+ (if (even? (string-length (first alist)))
             1
             0)
         (count-even-strings (rest alist)))))

(count-even-strings '("a" "ab" "c""))   ;; => 2
```

or, using a single conditional:

```
(define (count-even-strings alist)
  (cond ((empty? alist) 0)
        ((even? (string-length (first alist))) (+ 1 (count-even-strings (rest alist))))
        (else (count-even-strings (rest alist)))))
```